# Swift CollectionView (fatal error: Index out of range)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I am implementing a UICollectionView inside each cell of a UITableView
Now I am getting data from an API and keeping this data in an Array, and the problem is that the UICollectionView delegate method numberOfItemsInSection is of course being called before even the array is getting filled with data so I am getting Index out of range error.
The question is how to give maybe a default value to the count being returned or how to mutate the array.
Here is the code i am using:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  //  let cell = collectionView.superview as! MainTableViewCell
 //   let index = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)
    let countIndex = self.consultations[collectionView.tag].images.count

    return countIndex
}
```

Comment: You probably have an issue with cell re-use.  It shouldn't matter if `numberOfItems` is called before the data is provided; you should clear the array on re-use.  `self.consultations` should always be in a coherent state.  Also, relying on `tag`s is fragile. Your cell should just have an `images` array; it shouldn't need to know about any enclosing array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check array found and it's count.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
if let consultationsTmp = self.consultations, let colTag = consultationsTmp[collectionView.tag],let imagesTmp = colTag.images
            {
      return imagesTmp.count
            }
return 0
}
```

Comment: Thanx man but i have an other question , how can i get the index of the UITableViewCell in which there is the UICollectionView?

Comment: Please post an other question with all details.Please accept and upvote the answer.

Answer (score -1):

I solved the issue with a different method.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let cell = collectionView.superview?.superview?.superview as! MainTableViewCell
    print("SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS\(cell)")
    let index = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: cell.center)
    print("EEEEEEEEEEEEEE\(index?.row)")
    let countIndex = self.consultations[index?.row ?? 00].images.count

    return countIndex
}
```